# DIV Row & HRs Extend Beyond Container (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I have a DIV and a HR pushing out of their Container. I've tried several different fixes, but nothing seems to work. I've placed everything in a Fiddle so you can take a look at what I'm talking about. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.copy {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.leadMargin {
  margin-left: 10px;
  postion: relative;
}

.hr {
  clear: both;
  border: 3px solid #f5f5f5;
  margin-top: 110px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.noMargin {
  margin: 0;
}

.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="">Post Block</h1>
  <hr>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400X200" class="img-responsive"  alt="placeholder image" />
      <p class="lead">Responsive Design</p>
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs turkey ut et cillum, capicola culpa turducken t-bone. Adipisicing officia pork loin, nulla andouille in eu capicola. Landjaeger pork chop sed kielbasa boudin aliqua. Salami pork ground round, jerky fatback ut eiusmod.
        Nisi ball tip do pig shankle turducken. Velit nisi t-bone pork tail corned beef salami pancetta cupidatat sirloin eu sint jowl. Qui cow voluptate pastrami.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" class="img " alt="lady with senior lady" />

          <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 ">
            <p class="lead noMargin">New Collection of Shortcodes</p>
            <p>Landjaeger pork chop sed kielbasa boudin aliqua. Salami pork ground round, jerky fatback ut eiusmod. Nisi ball tip do pig shankle turducken.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hr">
        </div>

        <div class="row position-relative">
          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" class="img" alt="lady with senior lady" />
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            <p class="lead noMargin">New Collection of Shortcodes</p>
            <p>Landjaeger pork chop sed kielbasa boudin aliqua. Salami pork ground round, jerky fatback ut eiusmod. Nisi ball tip do pig shankle turducken.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hr">
        </div>
        <div class="row"> <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" class="img" alt="lady with senior lady" />
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            <p class="lead noMargin">New Collection of Shortcodes</p>
            <p>Landjaeger pork chop sed kielbasa boudin aliqua. Salami pork ground round, jerky fatback ut eiusmod. Nisi ball tip do pig shankle turducken.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="hr">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.
Kyle

Comment: What's with all the positiioning...that seems odd when using Bootstrap?...the clearing `hr` with margins is strange too.

Comment: Why are you using both container and container-fluid in the same div? [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the double container classes. I had `<div class="container container-fluid">`. When I removed the first container class the `<HR>`s started behaving.